# Node.JS - ChildProcess Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, child-process

Like my title says, I'm trying to combine the Mongo-Watch module (https://github.com/TorchlightSoftware/mongo-watch) and the Variety module (https://github.com/variety/variety) so that I can have Variety return all the keys for a MongoDB collection when it's been modified. Because Variety is a command-line tool, I am using childspawn.exec to initiate it (it will dump results into another MongoDB collection).

When the code below runs, it seems to initiate the command an arbitrary number of times until I get a "Error: spawn EMFILE." Any thoughts?

If I run "exec(cmd...)" by itself, without wrapping it within watcher, it runs as it should - which is once.
If I substitute cmd for a simple "ls" (like the Unix ls command), it works perfectly, displaying results for one ls call.

Thanks!

```
var cmd = "mongo " + config.dbUrl + " --eval " + '\"var collection = \'' + config.collect[0] + '\'\"' + " variety.js "
var target = db[config.collect[0]]; //eg. varietyResults.test3
watcher.watch(target, function(event) { //Watch Mongo oplog for any changes to source
   exec(cmd, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
        console.log(stdout);
        })
 });
```

Comment: The `EMFILE` error is related to having too many file descriptors open. I would guess that you are hitting current limits when you get a large batch of updates to the collection you are watching (which in turn kicks off a number of parallel `exec()s`). You could increase your ulimits, but there's probably a more efficient pattern here (for example, periodically running Variety via cron).

Comment: That makes sense, but interestingly enough I still get that error if I only update my collection by inserting a single document, which would be akin to running Variety on its own right?

Comment: Hello user3700442, I'm James Cropcho, the creator of Variety, and I just saw this. Did you ever figure it out? Let me know, if you have a free moment. Also consider asking at https://github.com/variety/variety/issues, as it's fairly active. Anyway, good luck!